# Why https website leave http port open?

Tags: security, http, https, ports

Most of the website which use https protocol to communicate have the HTTP port of the web server in open position. Is there any need for it to be left open ?

Comment: If they _also_ serve the `http` protocol, then certainly the port has to remain open. If the server _only_ `https`, then the port obviously can be closed. It does not raise any security issues if a port is not filtered, unless there is a service handling communication on that port.

Answer (score 0):

If the website serve https, it may leaves http open to redirect requests to https: Even if the websites use HSTS preloaded, older browsers may not be aware.

- Links to the websites may be (wrongly) prefixed by http://
- Users can write the domain name in the url (so the browser will prefix by http://)

There is few security advantage to close the http ports for an https only website.